# How do I cut a number from following file

Tags: unix

I have a file in Unix, having following containt.

```
{
BTEQ 13.10.00.06 Mon Jun  3 03:01:13 2013

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
 logon TDDEV/TVDW_APP,

 *** Logon successfully completed.
 *** Teradata Database Release is 13.00.01.06                   
 *** Teradata Database Version is 13.00.01.06                     
 *** Transaction Semantics are BTET.
 *** Session Character Set Name is 'ASCII'.

 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
call TVDW_APP.PROC_OPO_GET_MAX_BATCH_ID(V_MAX_BATCH_ID);

 *** Procedure has been executed. 
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

V_MAX_BATCH_ID
--------------
             9

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
 *** BTEQ exiting due to EOF on stdin.

 *** Exiting BTEQ...
 *** RC (return code) = 0 
}
```

I want to extract the number "9" from this file and assign it to a variable.
How do I do this? Plese help.
(I am writting a ksh file for this purpose; The number 9 is in 22nd line, characters 11 to 14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed  "1,/^V_MAX_BATCH_ID/d" < input.txt | sed -n "/^\s*[0-9]\s*$/p" | sed "s/\s//g")
```

1. Delete all lines up to `V_MAX_BATCH_ID`.
2. From the following lines print only those that only contain a single digit.
3. Strip all whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the number is on the 23rd line, you can use a single `sed` as shown below:

```
$ foo=$(sed -n '23s/^ *//p' file)
$ echo "$foo"
9
```

Alternatively, you can look for `V_MAX_BATCH_ID` and pick the second line below it using a single `sed` as shown below:

```
$ foo=$(sed -n '/^V_MAX_BATCH_ID/{n;n;s/ *//p}' file)
$ echo "$foo"
9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^V_MAX_BATCH_ID$/{getline;getline;gsub(/ /,"");print}' your_file
```

Comment: Why `gsub(/ /,"");print`?  Why not `print $1`?